# how to extract cookies using regexp?

Tags: php, regex

I am using :

```
(?<=^Set-Cookie:\s).+(?=;)
```

On

```
Set-Cookie: bbsessionhash=a163f6f9788776f36019a5945d075611; path=/; HttpOnly
```

How can I extract this string :

```
bbsessionhash=a163f6f9788776f36019a5945d075611
```

Comment: Why can't you use `$_COOKIE` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are matching the whole (outgoing?) header, then it's best to match it completely, not partially:

```
/(?<=^Set-Cookie:)\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)\s*;/im
```

If you want to match *all* headers, then you could keep the first \w, but replace the second with `[^\s;]` to match more arbitrary values.